# Summing a column of numbers in a text file using Perl

Tags: perl

Ok, so I'm very new to Perl. I have a text file and in the file there are 4 columns of data(date, time, size of files, files). I need to create a small script that can open the file and get the average size of the files. I've read so much online, but I still can't figure out how to do it. This is what I have so far, but I'm not sure if I'm even close to doing this correctly.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

open FILE, "files.txt";
#@array = File;

while(FILE){
    #chomp;

    ($date, $time, $numbers, $type) = split(/ /,<FILE>);

    $total += $numbers;

}
print"the total is $total\n";
```

This is how the data looks in the file. These are just a few of them. I need to get the numbers in the third column.

```
12/02/2002  12:16 AM              86016 a2p.exe
10/10/2004  11:33 AM               393 avgfsznew.pl
11/01/2003  04:42 PM             38124 c2ph.bat
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your program is reasonably close to working. With these changes it will do exactly what you want

- *Always* use `use strict` and `use warnings` at the start of your program, and declare all of your variables using `my`. That will help you by finding many simple errors that you may otherwise overlook
- Use lexical file handles, the three-parameter form of `open`, and *always* check the return status of any `open` call
- Declare the `$total` variable outside the loop. Declaring it inside the loop means it will be created and destroyed each time around the loop and it won't be able to accumulate a total
- Declare a `$count` variable in the same way. You will need it to calculate the average
- Using `while (FILE) {...}` just tests that `FILE` is true. You need to read from it instead, so you must use the `readline` operator like `<FILE>`
- You want the *default* call to `split` (without any parameters) which will return all the non-space fields in `$_` as a list
- You need to add a variable in the assignment to allow for athe `AM` or `PM` field in each line

Here is a modification of your code that works fine

```
use strict;
use warnings;

open my $fh, '<', "files.txt" or die $!;

my $total = 0;
my $count = 0;

while (<$fh>) {

    my ($date, $time, $ampm, $numbers, $type) = split;

    $total += $numbers;
    $count += 1;

}

print "The total is $total\n";
print "The count is $count\n";
print "The average is ", $total / $count, "\n";
```

**output**

```
The total is 124533
The count is 3
The average is 41511
```

Comment: This is excellent, as it's detailed, well-written, and well-matched to the OP who's "...very new to Perl."

Comment: I cannot thank you enough for your help. You made it very easy for me to understand and follow what was being done. Thank You!!!

Answer (score 14):

It's tempting to use Perl's `awk`-like auto-split option.  There are 5 columns; three containing date and time information, then the size and then the name.

The first version of the script that I wrote is also the most verbose:

```
perl -n -a -e '$total += $F[3]; $num++; END { printf "%12.2f\n", $total / ($num + 0.0); }'
```

The `-a` (auto-split) option splits a line up on white space into the array `@F`.  Combined with the `-n` option (which makes Perl run in a loop that reads the file name arguments in turn, or standard input, without printing each line), the code adds `$F[3]` (the fourth column, counting from 0) to `$total`, which is automagically initialized to zero on first use.  It also counts the lines in `$num`.  The `END` block is executed when all the input is read; it uses `printf()` to format the value.  The `+ 0.0` ensures that the arithmetic is done in floating point, not integer arithmetic.  This is very similar to the `awk` script:

```
awk '{ total += $4 } END { print total / NR }'
```

First drafts of programs are seldom optimal — or, at least, I'm not that good a programmer.  Revisions help.

Perl was designed, in part, as an `awk` killer.  There is still a program `a2p` distributed with Perl for converting `awk` scripts to Perl (and there's also `s2p` for converting `sed` scripts to Perl).  And Perl does have an automatic (built-in) variable that keeps track of the number of lines read.  It has several names.  The tersest is `$.`; the mnemonic name `$NR` is available if you [`use English;`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#Variables-related-to-filehandles) in the script; so is `$INPUT_LINE_NUMBER`.  So, using `$num` is not necessary.  It also turns out that Perl does a floating point division anyway, so the `+ 0.0` part was unnecessary.  This leads to the next versions:

```
perl -MEnglish -n -a -e '$total += $F[3]; END { printf "%12.2f\n", $total / $NR; }'
```

or:

```
perl -n -a -e '$total += $F[3]; END { printf "%12.2f\n", $total / $.; }'
```

You can tune the print format to suit your whims and fancies.  This is essentially the script I'd use in the long term; it is fairly clear without being long-winded in any way.  The script could be split over multiple lines if you desired.  It is a simple enough task that the legibility of the one-line is not a problem, IMNSHO.  And the beauty of this is that you don't have to futz around with `split` and arrays and read loops on your own; Perl does most of that for you.  (Granted, it does blow up on empty input; that fix is trivial; see below.)

#### Recommended version

```
perl -n -a -e '$total += $F[3]; END { printf "%12.2f\n", $total / $. if $.; }'
```

The `if $.` tests whether the number of lines read is zero or not; the `printf` and division are omitted if `$.` is zero so the script outputs nothing when given no input.

---

There is a noble (or ignoble) game called 'Code Golf' that was much played in the early days of Stack Overflow, but Code Golf questions are no longer considered good questions.  The object of Code Golf is to write a program that does a particular task in as few characters as possible.  You can play Code Golf with this and compress it still further if you're not too worried about the format of the output and you're using at least Perl 5.10:

```
perl -Mv5.10 -n -a -e '$total += $F[3]; END { say $total / $. if $.; }'
```

And, clearly, there are a lot of unnecessary spaces and letters in there:

```
perl -Mv5.10 -nae '$t+=$F[3];END{say$t/$.if$.}'
```

That is not, however, as clear as the recommended version.

Comment: What nonsense. This guy is struggling to write the simplest of Perl programs and you regale him with this!

Comment: So you prefer 15 lines to 2?  Wow!

Comment: It may entertain you to flex your programming muscle, but it isn't any help to many people. Anything can be written in one line, and I am sure you write *some* multi-line programs. Why exactly?

Comment: @Borodin Maybe it's over the top for the OP but he's not the only one who will read this. It's cool to show there's more to learn and that TIMTOWTDI. +1 from me.

Comment: It's true that OP is not the only one who will read this, but he's the one who should profit from the answer in the first place. It makes sense to write a readable, easily comprehended answer so that he will understand what's going on.

Comment: @Borodin This article can be read by everyone, who is trying to make his programming in Linux more elegant. +1 from me too.

Answer (score 2):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;

open my $file, "<", "files.txt";
my ($total, $cnt);
while(<$file>){
        $total += (split(/\s+/, $_))[3];
        $cnt++;
}
close $file;
print  "number of files: $cnt\n";
print  "total size: $total\n";
printf "avg: %.2f\n", $total/$cnt;
```

Or you can use `awk`:

```
awk '{t+=$4} END{print t/NR}' files.txt
```

Comment: I prefer 1 line of `awk` to 13 of Perl.  Of course, it can also be done in one line of Perl.

Answer (score 1):

Try doing this :

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -l

use strict; use warnings;

open my $file, '<', "my_file" or die "open error [$!]";

my ($total, $count);

while (<$file>){
    chomp;
    next if /^$/;
    my ($date, $time, $x, $numbers, $type) = split;
    $total += $numbers;
    $count++;
}

print "the average is " . $total/$count . " and the total is $total";

close $file;
```

Comment: Code without explanation is no answer.

Answer (score 0):

This solution opens the file and loops through each line of the file. It then splits the file into the five variables in the line by splitting on 1 or more spaces.

- open the file for reading, `"<"`, and if it fails, raise an error `or die "..."`
- `my ($total, $cnt)` are our column total and number of files added count
- `while(<FILE>) { ... }` loops through each line of the file using the file handle and stores the line in `$_`
- `chomp` removes the input record separator in `$_`. In unix, the default separator is a newline `\n`
- `split(/\s+/, $_)` Splits the current line represented by`$_`, with the delimiter `\s+`. `\s` represents a space, the `+` afterward means "1 or more". So, we split the next line on 1 or more spaces.
- Next we update `$total` and `$cnt`

  ```
  #!/usr/bin/perl

  open FILE, "<", "files.txt" or die "Error opening file: $!";
  my ($total, $cnt);

  while(<FILE>){
    chomp;
    my ($date, $time, $am_pm, $numbers, $type) = split(/\s+/, $_); 
    $total += $numbers;
    $cnt++; 
  }
  close FILE;

  print"the total is $total and count of $cnt\n";`
  ```

Comment: To quote @darch: "Code without explanation is no answer."

Comment: Oops, I don't know what I was thinking. Fixed

Answer (score 0):

It is as simple as this:

```
perl -F -lane '$a+=$F[3];END{print "The average size is ".$a/$.}' your_file
```

tested below:

```
> cat temp
12/02/2002  12:16 AM              86016 a2p.exe
10/10/2004  11:33 AM               393 avgfsznew.pl
11/01/2003  04:42 PM             38124 c2ph.bat
```

Now the execution:

```
> perl -F -lane '$a+=$F[3];END{print "The average size is ".$a/$.}' temp
The average size is 41511
>
```

**explanation:**
-F -a   says store the line in an array format.with the default separator as space or tab.
so nopw $F[3] has you size of the file.
sum up all the sizes in the 4th column untill all the lines are processed.
END will be executed after processing all the lines in the file.

so $. at the end will gives the number of lines.
so $a/$. will give the average.